# Conversion failed when converting date or time from character string

Tags: sql, visual-studio, date, insert

This is my insert statement to insert data into database. This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO JobsDB (Job_Name, Job_Desc, Job_Categ, Job_Qualif, Job_PayType, Job_Payrate, Job_PloyerName, Job_StartDate, Job_EndDate, Job_Status) VALUES ('" + tbName.Text + "' , '" + tbDescription.Text + "' , '" + ddCategory.Text + "' , '" + ddQualifications.Text + "' , '" + ddPayType.Text + "' , '" + tbRate.Text + "' , 'Kaslana' , '" + calendarStart.SelectedDate + "' , '" + calendarEnd.SelectedDate + "' , 'Active')
```

The error occurs at the point where the code takes the selected date from the calendar control and trys to insert it into the database.

Comment: Use parameters.  You'll never have this particular problem again.

Comment: What's the exception Message?

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert.ToDateTime(YourSelectedDate)

```
INSERT INTO JobsDB (Job_Name, Job_Desc, Job_Categ, Job_Qualif, Job_PayType, Job_Payrate, Job_PloyerName, Job_StartDate, Job_EndDate, Job_Status) 
VALUES ('" + tbName.Text + "' , '" + tbDescription.Text + "' , '" + ddCategory.Text + "' , '" + ddQualifications.Text + "' , '" + ddPayType.Text + "' , '" + tbRate.Text + "' , 'Kaslana' , '" + Convert.ToDateTime(calendarStart.SelectedDate) + "' , '" +Convert.ToDateTime(calendarEnd.SelectedDate) + "' , 'Active')
```